# How to build a universal wheel with pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

This is the project directory structure

```
.
├── meow.py
└── pyproject.toml

0 directories, 2 files
```

This is the `meow.py`:

```
def main():
    print("meow world")
```

This is the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "meowpkg"
version = "0.1"
description = "a package that meows"

[project.scripts]
meow_world = "meow:main"
```

When building this package, no matter whether with `python3 -m pip wheel .` or using `python3 -m build`, it creates a file named like `meowpkg-0.1-py3-none-any.whl` which can not be installed on Python 2.

```
$ python2.7 -m pip install meowpkg-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: meowpkg-0.1-py3-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

But "meowpkg" actually works on Python 2 as well. How to instruct setuptools and/or wheel to create a universal wheel tagged like `meowpkg-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`, without using the old `setup.cfg`/`setup.py` ways?

Current workaround:

```
echo "[bdist_wheel]\nuniversal=1" > setup.cfg && python3 -m build && rm setup.cfg
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add this section into the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.distutils.bdist_wheel]
universal = true
```

Comment: Does this actually work? When I include this and run `python -m build`, I get `Command option bdist_wheel.universal is not defined` and build a wheel with `macosx` in the name (not universal).

Comment: This doesn't work for me (Python 3.11.3, pip 23.1.1, setuptools 67.6.1, wheel 0.40.0). Neither does `universal = 1`. Back to using `setup.cfg`